# Eshop with sockets - file reading/writing problem

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface, server, client

I have a question about package structure and reading and writing into files.

I am coding an eshop to learn java and now implented data exchange via sockets.

Since I am not using a data bank I am using .txt-files to write articles, new customers etc. into it.
[image]

I now wanted to place the txt files into the server module in a package named "ressources". But then the compiler always said he couldn't find the files.
I then named him the exact path to the "ressources" package and the reading worked.

```
public void openForReading(String dataSource) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //New code
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + dataSource);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    //old code, compiler said he couldn't find the file
    //reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataSource));
}
```

But when I registered a new customer and wrote him into the files he created a new file in the project directory instead of refreshing the file on the server in the package "ressources".
I could fix that too with this code. but now he only refreshes the files in the directory "out".

```
public void openForWriting(String dataSource) throws IOException {
    //New code
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/" + dataSource);        
    File file = new File(url.getPath());
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));

    //old code, not working - creates new file
    //writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataSource)));
}
```

Is there a way to refresh the files on the server and in the directory out?

Comment: Are you going to be *writing* data *at runtime*? That's important, as then the target is not a resource, but a data file and must be treated as a file in the file system, probably in an app directory off `${user.home}`

Comment: Yes the data is written into the files at runtime.. So I can't have a resources package then? What do you mean by user.home?

Comment: No you can't. You want `mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\.EShop\data"` from cmd.exe. Put your data files in there

Comment: I honestly have to say I am not quite sure If I got that. 
So I have to go into the cmd and enter "mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\.EShop\data" there. 

But where in intellij do I have to put the files?

Comment: Yes. You don't put the files anywhere to do with IntelliJ. But you can drag them into the correct location which you'll see if you follow that command with `explorer "%USERPROFILE%\.EShop\data"`